# Erro alterar com mensagem Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

Tags: c#

Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema.

Criei um classe para DTO assim:

```
public class PessoaFuncionario
{
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string CRM { get; set; }

}
```

Ela usa a outra que `Pessoa` que esta assim:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int IDPessoa { get; set; }
    public PessoaTipo PessoaTipo { get; set; }
}
```

Criei então um objeto negocios com as regras para inserir:

```
public string Alterar(PessoaFuncionario pessoaFuncionario)
{
    try
    {
        acessoDadosSqlServer.LimparParametros();                
        acessoDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@IDPessoaFuncionario", pessoaFuncionario.Pessoa.IDPessoa);
        acessoDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@Nome", pessoaFuncionario.Nome);
        acessoDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@CPF", pessoaFuncionario.CPF);
        acessoDadosSqlServer.AdicionarParametros("@CRM", pessoaFuncionario.CRM);

        string idPessoaFuncionario = acessoDadosSqlServer.ExecutarManipulacao(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "uspPessoaFuncionarioAlterar").ToString();
        return idPessoaFuncionario;
    }
    catch (Exception excpetion)
    {
        return excpetion.Message;
    }
}
```

E o método no botão para alterar:

```
else if (acaoNaTelaSelecionada == AcaoNaTela.Alterar)
{
    PessoaFuncionario pessoaFunc = new PessoaFuncionario();
    pessoaFunc.Pessoa.IDPessoa = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text); // << Onde aparece o erro
    pessoaFunc.Nome = txtNome.Text;
    pessoaFunc.CRM = txtCRM.Text;
    pessoaFunc.CPF = mskCPF.Text;

    PessoaFuncionarioNegocios pessoaNegocios = new PessoaFuncionarioNegocios();
    string retorna = pessoaNegocios.Alterar(pessoaFunc);

    try
    {
        int IDPessoa = Convert.ToInt32(retorna);
        MessageBox.Show("Registro atualizado com sucesso.", "Sucesso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Não foi possivel alterar. Detalhes: " + retorna, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

O erro ocorre no inicio do método salvar.

Mas esta emitindo erro dizendo *Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto*.

Fiz desse mesmo jeito para o *inserir* e *excluir* e ambos estão funcionando normalmente. Só o *alterar* que esta acusando esse erro. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Em qual linha acusa o erro?

Comment: Logo no inicio da chama do método alterar. 

            else if (acaoNaTelaSelecionada == AcaoNaTela.Alterar)
            {
                PessoaFuncionario funcionario = new PessoaFuncionario();
                funcionario.Pessoa.IDPessoa = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text); <<<<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Também é necessário inicializar a classe `Pessoa`.

```
PessoaFuncionario pessoaFunc = new PessoaFuncionario();
pessoaFunc.Pessoa.IDPessoa = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text); // <-- erro aqui
```

Você deve fazer:

```
PessoaFuncionario pessoaFunc = new PessoaFuncionario();
pessoaFunc.Pessoa = new Pessoa(); // <-- 
pessoaFunc.Pessoa.IDPessoa = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);
```

Ou inicializa-la na classe `PessoaFuncionario`:

```
public class PessoaFuncionario
{
     public Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa(); // <--
     public string Nome { get; set; }
     public string CPF { get; set; }
     public string CRM { get; set; }
}
```

E usá-la assim:

```
PessoaFuncionario pessoaFunc = new PessoaFuncionario();
pessoaFunc.pessoa.IDPessoa = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);
```

Comment: Tentei como você falou mas o pessoaFunc começa a acusar erro dizendo que não foi encontrado namespace ou referencias a ele.

também tentei 

                PessoaFuncionario pessoaFunc = new PessoaFuncionario();
                Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
                pessoa.IDPessoa = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);
                pessoaFunc.Pessoa.IDPessoa = pessoa.IDPessoa;

Mas o erro anterior persiste =/

Comment: @George Já arrumo isso, postei também uma outra forma,.

Comment: Usei assim 

                pessoaFunc.Pessoa = new Pessoa();
                pessoaFunc.Pessoa.IDPessoa = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);
                pessoaFunc.Nome = txtNome.Text;
                pessoaFunc.CPF = mskCPF.Text;
                pessoaFunc.CRM = txtCRM.Text;


E funcionou :D


Muito obrigado. Vlw mesmo

Comment: Quanto ao segundo conselho: [(quase) **nunca** se devem usar fields publicos](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx).

Comment: @dcastro Obrigado pelo conselho. =)